# Creating and start animation

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

### I did the following:

**Create file AnimationClick.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:oneshot="true">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ButtonState1" android:duration="250"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ButtonState2" android:duration="250"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ButtonState3" android:duration="250"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/ButtonState4" android:duration="250"/>
</animation-list>
```

**And create file ItemImage.axml:**

```
<ImageView
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/LeSommet.ZooSnap.UI.Android"
      android:layout_width="80dp"
      android:layout_height="80dp"
      android:padding="5dp"
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:src="@drawable/AnimationClick"
  />
```

**To run this animation should do the following:**

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.imageAnimation);
 animation = (AnimationDrawable)image.Drawable;
 animation.Start();
```

*imageAnimation* - My ImageView.

**But I use a GridView in which 20 ItemImage. How to start an animation when pressed on one of the ImageView?**

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I think the easiest way is to create a custom control and to trigger the animation within that control.

To see how to do this for a list, take a look at the answers for: [How to create view's actions listener for MvxItemTemplate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12934654/how-to-create-views-actions-listener-for-mvxitemtemplate)